# MySql Error::error in sql syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

MySql query below:

```
SELECT Name, 
SUM(Balance) AS Balance, 
(IF (Balance<=0), abs(Balance), 0 ) AS Exc, 
(IF (Balance>=0), Balance, 0 ) AS Del  
from table1 group by name
```

Mysql error:

```
You have an error in your sql syntax; check manual that corresponds to your MySql server version for the right syntax to use near
```

Comment: You cannot combine SUM(Balance) and Balance in the query with group by

Comment: There is another issue with the IF(). Check out [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

Comment: "for the right syntax to use near' *what?* Why have you left out the most useful part of the error message?

Comment: actually you want the `sum` to be checked for `+Ve /-Ve ` or the `value` in `Balance`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CASE ... WHEN conditinnal statement like this

```
    SELECT Name, 
    SUM(Balance) AS Balance,
    (CASE WHEN SUM(Balance)>=0 THEN SUM(Balance) WHEN SUM(Balance)<0 THEN SUM(Balance) * -1 END) AS Balance_Positive
    from table1 group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, 
SUM(Balance) AS Balance, 
IF( (SUM(Balance)<=0), abs(SUM(Balance)), 0 ) AS Exc, 
IF( (SUM(Balance)>=0),SUM(Balance), 0 ) AS Del  
from table1 group by Name
```